# Yii refresh updated user

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Simple example.

We have simple `login\auth` methods (so i won't show them). On ajax request we change some user values (in db) in resoponce we call `Yii::app()->user->someMethod()` and we will not get latest data (i mean from db). I understand why, because user `init()` on start Yii so data will be old through all code until refresh. On refresh user `init()` again and we see actual data.

Question is, how to refresh user like simple model `User::model()->refresh()` to get actual data from db?

Comment: Please check the following link: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/60/#c10393

Comment: You may need to create a class extends CWebUser and implement it method `update()` which will update the user data from database.